# Using LSH in spark to run nearest neighbors query on every point in dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-sql

I need k nearest neighbors for each feature vector in the dataframe. I'm using BucketedRandomProjectionLSHModel from pyspark.

code for creating the model

```
brp = BucketedRandomProjectionLSH(inputCol="features", outputCol="hashes",seed=12345, bucketLength=n)

model = brp.fit(data_df)
df_lsh = model.transform(data_df)
```

Now, How do I run approx nearest neighbor query for each point in data_df.

I have tried broadcasting the model but got pickle error.
Also, defining a  udf to access the model gives error `Method __getstate__([]) does not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use should use `.approxSimilarityJoin`

```
model.df_lsh(df_lsh, df_lsh)
```