# Create a column of ArrayType[StructType] from Dataframe in a UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I created a BucketedRandomProjectionLSHModel in order to find out the approximate nearest neighbours for every row in my dataset. The signature for the approximate nearest function is

```
def approxNearestNeighbors(
      dataset: Dataset[_],
      key: Vector,
      numNearestNeighbors: Int): Dataset[_]
```

To run it on every row of the dataframe, my idea is to create some udf which calls this function and convert the resulting Dataset into a column of ArrayType[StructType].

Suppose my initial schema is

```
root
 |-- genderIndex: double (nullable = false)
 |-- genderIndexVec: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- categoryIndex: double (nullable = false)
 |-- categoryIndexVec: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- featureStdDev: vector (nullable = true)
```

My target schema (after calling .withColumn($"featureStdDev", udf...)) is

```
root
 |-- genderIndex: double (nullable = false)
 |-- genderIndexVec: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- categoryIndex: double (nullable = false)
 |-- categoryIndexVec: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- featureStdDev: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- neighbours: array(nullable = true)
      |-- elem: struct
           |-- genderIndex: double (nullable = false)
           |-- genderIndexVec: vector (nullable = true)
           |-- categoryIndex: double (nullable = false)
           |-- categoryIndexVec: vector (nullable = true)
           |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
           |-- featureStdDev: vector (nullable = true)
```

Please help with my UDF as I am not sure how to make it work.

```
val model = // BucketedRandomProjectionLSHModel definition
val inputDF = // Input definition
val nn = udf{ (featureVector: SparseVector, k: Int) =>
      model.approxNearestNeighbors(inputDF, featureVector, k)
      // What now...
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LSH in spark to run nearest neighbors query on every point in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119437/using-lsh-in-spark-to-run-nearest-neighbors-query-on-every-point-in-dataframe)

Comment: @Shaido Approx Similarity Join does slightly different things. A similarity join against the df itself will either get an exact copy or a highly similar "neighbour", i.e. you cannot tell whether the feature vector has a similar neighbour within the df, but approx nearest neighbours can guarantee to find k (or less than k, which means there are not enough) similar neighbours.

Comment: Yes, for the similarity join you need to specify a threshold so there is no guarantee to get a specific number of (or any at all) neighbors. Unfortunatly as far as I can see, `approxNearestNeighbors` currently only support single vector inputs, which is why you want to use an UDF. The problem with the UDF appraoch is that you can't refer to a dataframe inside an UDF, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509249/how-to-pass-dataframe-as-input-to-spark-udf

Comment: @Shaido That's very useful. I shall see if there is other ways than UDF which I can achieve the results.